# 2D Graphics Acceleration

Tags: c++, c, mobile

I have noticed that some modern mobile hardware support 2D hardware accelerated bitBLT operations. Is there are any fairly standard libraries that allow an application developer to take advantage of 2D hardware acceleration? (Something that is for 2D what OpenGL is for 3D would be nice)

Edit: I know that OpenGL can be used for 2D operations but when one uses openGL one uses the 3D Hardware block and not the 2D hardware block. I am looking for an API that makes direct use of the 2D hardware block.

Answer (score -1):

`OpenGL` can be used not only for 3d, but for 2d too. So the answer is: `OpenGL`

Almost every game on the market (including 2d games) use `OpenGL` for rendering. You might want to take a look at `Cocos2d-x`. It is a crossplatform c++ game engine, that use OpenGL for 2d graphics

Comment: I wouldn't entirely agree with your second paragraph. SDL is used quite a bit in LinuxLand, and DirectX can do 2D as well.

Comment: @JamWaffles: SDL is built over OpenGL. Which mobile platform run DirectX?

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice the OP was looking for mobile libraries. Sorry `:)`.

Comment: Please see edit. I am specifically trying to target the 2D hardware block (and not the 3D GPU)

Comment: @doron: Sorry, I don't know such libriries